# Pivot a table in SQL using a column and finding max and min date

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, pivot, pivot-table

I have the following dataset with three columns Type, ID and Date

```
Type      ID    Date
A input   2     20190108
A output  2     20190111
B input   6     20190213
A input   2     20190311
A output  2     20190319
B input   5     20190217
B output  6     20190215
C input   5     20190121
B input   6     20190609
B output  5     20190219
C input   5     20190112
C output  5     20190126
B input   6     20190121
B output  6     20190611
C input   2     20190101
B output  6     20190128
C output  2     20190105
C output  5     20190115
```

I need to pivot this table to get the max date for input and output for each type

```
Type    ID  Input date  output date
A       2   20190311    20190319
B       6   20190609    20190611
C       5   20190217    20190219
```

How should I go about it? 
Should I first pivot the table and then find the max values? or vice versa?

Thanks

Comment: Is it really `A input' in one column or are those two columns?

Comment: Hi Salman, its just one column. I have separated it using a case statement into columns but I don't know how to go about it from there

Comment: I made a mistake actually. Will correct it in my question. it should be by id. so Id's would have multiple dates, so I need the max date for input and output.

Thanks for pointing that out

Comment: Question updated

Comment: Is id "2" really associated with both "C" and "A"?  What is the logic for disambiguating ids?

Comment: Yes it is. Id is related to a member which could belong to either groups

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to want aggregation with some string processing logic:

```
select substring_index(type, ' ', 1) as type, max(id) as id,
       max(case when type like '% input' then date end) as input_date,
       max(case when type like '% output' then date end) as output_date
from t
group by substring_index(type, ' ', 1);
```

EDIT:

The SQL Server version is:

```
select left(type, charindex(' ', type) - 1) as type, max(id) as id,
       max(case when type like '% input' then date end) as input_date,
       max(case when type like '% output' then date end) as output_date
from t
group by left(type, charindex(' ', type) - 1);
```

Comment: I just saw the substring_index and I realized I mistakenly put mysql as my db instead of sql-server. Sorry about that

Comment: @Standin.Wolf . . . In this case, it is easy to adjust the logic for SQL Server.

Comment: Hi Gordan,
Thanks for the reply. I am  getting NULL in the date fields. Also I am just getting 3 records in the output. 

In the question above there are 3 ids as an example but in my dataset I have like 1000 Ids hence it should display 1000 records. Let me know if i am not clear

Comment: I updated the query by removing max(id) and keeping it as id only and putting in group. I think I am almost there. Just need to get the date right instead of nulls